# Link shared folder from OS X to Debian

Tags: macos, debian, symlink, osx-elcapitan

I have shared a folder from my OS X El Capitan to Debian VM in scope of working my projects on my Mac machine and run them on Debian Server. I have shared the projects folder and symlink it to `/var/www/html`, but I can't access it. What I doing wrong or what I need to do to solve this? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You'll need to specify which Virtual Machine tool you're using, i.e. Virtual Box or Parallels or whatever.

Comment: I use VMware Fusion.